# How can I define argument type as a string from list of strings & run mongo db query

Tags: javascript, mongodb, nestjs

How can I define the arg type in a function as a string from list of strings and run a mongodb query. What I am doing is given below:

users.services.ts

```
async findOne(key: "_id" | "email" | "username", value: string) {
    
    const user = await this.userModel.findOne({ key: value }).exec();
    if (!user) {
      throw new NotFoundException();
    }
    return user;
  }
```

##### this is where & how I am calling `findOne` in `users.services.ts`

`const user = await this.usersService.findOne("username", username);`

Its not working and when debugging its not picking the values of key & value.
Many thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `$or` query

```
{
 $or: [
     {"_id": value},
     {"email": value},
     {"username": value}
 ]
}
```

It's better to have three/more different functions and make a call with the given key than having list of `or` conditions.